# 'Bucketization' - English or corporate speak?

Tags: verbs, terminology, business-language

I work in a BPO and sometimes we talk about 'bucketizing' an audience (segregating them based on performance/scores).
Does such a word exist or should I pass this off as corporate jargon? The word is not in any of the mainstream online dictionaries indexed by [OneLook Dictionary Search](https://www.onelook.com/?w=bucketize&ls=a).

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Dictionaries often flag usages restricted to niche registers. Questions lacking reasonable research may be closed as off-topic.

Comment: It's been around for probably 20 years, in corporate-speak.  A fairly mundane formation and easy to coin and to understand.  Probably hard to nail down an official "origin".

Comment: I bucketize my list frequently!

Answer (score 1):

***[Bucketize](https://www.aol.com/2011/02/20/buzzword-of-the-week-bucketize/)*** appears to have been made popular in Harvard:

> - ***Bucketize is (probably) not the most odious piece of slang to ever get the Harvard imprimatur*** and -- to be fair -- Mitzenmacher's position as the dean of computer science isn't the most stirring credential when it comes to wordsmithing. Even so, it's hard to get around the fact that Harvard has made its bid to give bucketize a veneer of legitimacy.
> - ....the word has already earned a somewhat controversial reputation. While it's gaining popularity in boardrooms, several watchdogs have classified it as one of the worst examples of bad business jargon.
>
>   Bucketize wasn't always quite so controversial. ***When it debuted in 2001, the word simply referred to putting food in containers, making it a rough synonym of "canning" or "containerizing."*** At about the same time, though, it was seized upon by technical writers and analysts, who used it to indicate a way of organizing data. Luckily, bucketize's status as a technical term meant that its use was largely limited to technical arenas for a few years.

(www.aol.com)

***[Bucketize](https://www.aol.com/2011/02/20/buzzword-of-the-week-bucketize/)***:

> - To separate into buckets or groups; to categorize.

(Wiktionary)